# Publishing toolchain with asciidoc / markdown input, html / pdf output

Tags: ruby, pdf, markdown, publishing, asciidoc

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2733170/publishing-toolchain) related question about publishing toolchain but I know many people did lot of work to produce publishing toolchains recently.

One great example I found is [this project](https://github.com/akosmasoftware/eBook-Template) from akosma.

Avdi Grimm shared his work with org-mode in [this project](https://github.com/avdi/orgpress)

I know there are (should be) many others.

What I'm looking for, is a publishing toolchain with

- asciidoc / markdown / textile / org-mode or latex input. I don't want xml input
- pdf AND html output, epub output is not a requirement for me.

What I can

- author templates in latex / html / css / js. again, no xml.
- read and write ruby and shell scripts

Comment: Use [pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc). It's not Ruby, though.

Comment: Yes pandoc is great converter, or dblatex .. but what i m looking for, is more "ready to use" scripts + css + latex templates (if any), taking your markdown / asciidoc, and converting them to shiny documents in pdf / html. I m using Adrian's template right know. But asking if there are similar ones.

Comment: Pandoc includes default templates for all output types. There are ruby bindings by the way: http://rdoc.info/github/alphabetum/pandoc-ruby https://github.com/alphabetum/pandoc-ruby

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at asciidoc, this is what O'Reilly has started using and it is a refreshing break from DocBook.   I use asciidoc, the tools and support leaves a little to be desired, but there are people working to create better alternatives (that don't involve Python and the existing Docbook pipeline).

Check out this: https://github.com/runemadsen/asciidoc

**EDIT 1/6/13**: You also really need to check out AsciiDoctor.   Dan Allen from RedHat has been spending a lot of time on this particular package and Ryan Waldron.   I expect great things from AsciiDoctor as it is starting to emerge as a foundation for a bunch of important AsciiDoc documentation efforts.

Comment: Thank you very much, i did see that repository when i asked this question, but never tried. Good to see people actively working on, and there is a final product built with that. I will definitely try it as soon as possible.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to asciidoctor. I really like the native ruby, unfortunately the documentation is still lacking.

Comment: After using Asciidoctor for a while I found it so amazing that I pitched it to our techdocs team and helped them migrate our docs into it. Thanks! huge time saver out of this little post.

Comment: Using asciidoctor for a while too. They made lots of progress since the time i asked question. This [link](http://asciidoctor.org/docs/install-toolchain/) and this [link](https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor-fopub) is especially useful for anyone interested.